# segmentation fault produced by tests running under CppUnit

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unix, cppunit

Today I found that one of my tests is using some code/library that segfaults.
I work in Linux environment in C++ and CppUnit.

Is there any  feature of function in CppUnit to test against segfault and report it as failure for the specific test case?

In CppUnit I can even test against exceptions, but I think that what I am asking might be too much! The only thing I found is the section How do I print debug info at this page [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

I was thinking to run the CppUnit executable from a script in pyhon or perl and then check if the core is produced. Do you know some better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Added unix tag - SEGFAULT is not generic.

Comment: Hi All. Thanks all for your responses. At the end I decided to run the test using GDB in batch mode.
It is a bit slower, but at least, in case of segmentation faults, it will log the exact point of the code [ file/line ] where the issue was.
I use the following command for that:
gdb ./testApp -ex "set args ./testClient.cfg" -ex r --batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seg fault will result in a non-zero exit status from your test (On Solaris I believe it's 139). Are you able to test this from whatever method is being used to call your unit test?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response..probably I asked the impossible...but in Linux I remember is also the same code so I might be checked.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any feature of function in CppUnit to test against segfault and report it as failure for the specific test case?"

Nope.  Segfault is an OS level violation and you're not allowed to catch it.  Even if you try (through use of signal() iirc) you can't do anything about being murdered by the OS.

You need to step through your test program with a debugger.

Comment: Um, cppunit could call sigaction and handle SIGSEGV, and report it as a failure.